# Can I bypass the current transaction in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I have some (php) code that performs critical updates on an InnoDB table.

I'm using (SELECT ... FOR UPDATE), so I need to be inside a transaction.

This code is being executed when data is posted from a form, and I have a message system in place so that error/success messages are stored in a database, and extracted from the database next time a page is rendered.

Some pseudocode:
(I'm ommitting stuff like the try/catch blocks and escaping that I have in my real code)

```
beginTransaction();

query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE");

$x=$_POST[$x];
query("UPDATE `table` SET `field` = $X");

//add other data in the db related to $X
query("INSERT INTO `othertable` (x,y,x) VALUES (......)");


//check for various errors...
$erros=0

if ($error_condition_1) {
    messageSystem("Error Condition 1!")
    $errors+=1;
}
if ($error_condition_2) {
    messageSystem("Error Condition 2!")
    $errors+=1;
}

if ($errors) {
    rollBackTransaction();
} else {
    commitTransaction();
}
```

The problem should be obvious: when messageSystem stores the error in the database the changes will be rolled back later, and the user will never see the error messages.

There are two easy solutions I can see:

1. Modify my code so that `messageSystem` is called outside the transaction. However it is more readable and quicker to write if I can do it inline like the above. Also, what if this is library code that may already be inside a nested transaction?
2. Modify `messageSystem` so that it uses its own connection to the database. But then what if I make messageSystem more complicated, and decide that it needs to lock an entry in the `session` table before it adds messages to that session. This could lead to a deadlock if my main code has also locked the session for some reason.
3. Check for errors before the transaction. But in actual fact I need to have locked the relevant rows by selecting 'FOR UPDATE' *before* I can validate the input.

And so my question: Is there any way to commit X when inside a (possibly nested) transaction such that if the transaction is rolled back, X will be committed anyway.

Alternatively is there any good way of avoiding the problem I've described.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a second database connection for your error logging.

Comment: Yeah, thats my current solution, and probably the best bet (+1), but I really want to know if there are other ways.

Comment: You should be assuming that each connection is for its own specific purpose, that way transaction isolation works properly.  If you need to use the database for a different reason (logging in this case), using another connection is the right way imho.

Comment: Sensible separation, and I think you are right for this situation. But what when it gets more complex? I already have a foreign key constraint from my messages table to my session table (so leftover messages get deleted when session dies). The session could be deleted during the above code. I can deal with this, but already the separation is not 100% clean. I'm interested in alternative answers so I can deal with it in more complex scenarios where there may not be a such good separation. Sorry for such a long comment.

Comment: I tend to use a debugging class that has its own connection to the database for output.  I use an instance of that class within each class I'm debugging, so that its logs get written out independantly.  It also lets me switch between file and sql debugging easily, as the calls don't have to change.  Not sure if this helps.